# How to pass the Page filename to Google Analytics trackEvent()

Tags: google-analytics, javascript

I want to easily view Events for a particular page in Google Analytics.

Is there a way to pass in the page filename to the event call?

e.g.,

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'ACTION-DESCRIPTION', 'ACTION','LABEL-usually-PAGE']);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a variable to store the pathname and then use that variable in the event

```
var path = document.location.pathname
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'category', 'action', 'path = '+path]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Google Tag Manager, as it allows you to define variables for event tracking.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this?

Comment: @nyuen helped me with a tracking question I had, so I would take his advice. But if you have Google Tag Manager set up on your site you can add custom variables to tags and triggers that fire on certain rules. https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6106899?hl=en&ref_topic=3441647&vid=1-635808550156658508-2060031959#web